# How can I load selective data from a serialized object in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, serialization

I am coding a 2-D RPG style, sprite-based game in Java for a school project and our group has decided that the game should have a camera that follows the player rather than a fixed one, which naturally means the game will need to load the world data dynamically as the player moves around. I know this can be achieved by loading sections of the world in chunks, like in Minecraft, but I'd like to be able to load small amounts data selectively and frequently rather than loading big chunks of data less frequently. For example, the player moves one unit up, so the game can discard the bottom row of data from memory while loading the top row, rather than loading an entire chunk or unloading a chunk every now and then. Currently all relevant world data is stored in 2-D arrays, so is there an efficient way to load specific data points in the arrays from the world file without having to load the entire thing or load it in big chunks?

Then again, maybe big chunk loading is the better option, since loading from the hard drive takes longer, any thoughts?

Let's say in that case that I have the world file made up of smaller files called areas which are basically chunks.

Then my question is: "How would I go about loading those specific areas from the main world file without loading the whole thing at once?"

Comment: so in short you want to store a matrix in a file and later you want to randomly access a sub-matrix from the file without going through the entire file?

Comment: @WasiAhmad Basically, yes.

Comment: Depends on the file format. If you can programmatically determine the offset for a given cell, you can seek to that offset and read. If you can't (cells have variable size), you'd have to index the serialized data so it's cell->offset. But for this, yes, disk seeking will kill you, and you can probably fit the entire world in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the [example](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/using-memory-mapped-file-for-huge.html) which can be used mainly for storing huge matrices since loading a huge matrix requires large amount of memory. Instead of loading in memory, if you store the matrix in a random access file, you can retrieve them very quickly. All you need to map a matrix to a [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) for later use. I am not iterating the whole example but only the main part which you need to understand clearly so that you can reimplement it as per your need.

```
public long position(int x, int y) {
    return (long) y * width + x;         // returns the position of a value in the file
}

public double get(int x, int y) {
    assert x <= 0 && x > width;          // simply bound check
    assert y <= 0 && y > height;         // simply bound check
    long p = position(x, y) * 8;         // 8 for double, if integer then use 4
    int mapN = (int) (p / MAPPING_SIZE);
    int offN = (int) (p % MAPPING_SIZE);
    return mappings.get(mapN).getDouble(offN);
}
```

`get` method retrieves value from a specific position (row, column) in a matrix stored in the file. `mappings` is just a data structure like `list` in java. Like `get` method, you need a `set` method as well.

```
public void set(int x, int y, double d) {
    assert x <= 0 && x > width;
    assert y <= 0 && y > height;
    long p = position(x, y) * 8;
    int mapN = (int) (p / MAPPING_SIZE);
    int offN = (int) (p % MAPPING_SIZE);
    mappings.get(mapN).putDouble(offN, d);
}
```

**Important**: `MAPPING_SIZE` can be set to `1 << 31` or a lower value because **Java** doesn't support mappings of 2 GB (2^31) or more at a time. So, if you use set `MAPPING_SIZE = 1 << 30`, it partitions the file into 1 GB mappings. For simplicity, you can think of it as splitting a large matrix and store them in small pieces (these are called mapping). If you have a small matrix, then you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Ah thank you, this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for!

Comment: @GregorySalazar best way to thank is through accepting the answer and giving an upvote ;)

Comment: Sorry I'm new on here, I upvoted you but it says it won't show because my reputation isn't high enough yet

Comment: @GregorySalazar you can accept the answer as you are the question owner :)